# Sublime Text 2 - Add characters to the auto match settings

Tags: sublimetext2, textile

Is it possible to add characters to the list that sublime text 2 uses for the auto match feature.

This is how it is described in the preferences.

```
// Controls auto pairing of quotes, brackets etc
"auto_match_enabled": true,
```

I would like to add;

```
* _
```

to the list because i'm writing a lot in the textile markup language.

Comment: If you haven't found this or aren't yet using it, I would highly suggest [BracketHighlighter2](https://github.com/facelessuser/BracketHighlighter/tree/BH2)

Answer (score 1):

I haven't had a chance to look through these in detail yet, but I have just run into the same problem, and the following are looking like good resources:

http://brettterpstra.com/2012/05/17/markdown-editing-for-sublime-text-2-humble-beginnings/

http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&p=29300

[Sublime Text 2--Doubled Autopaired Characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14260649/sublime-text-2-doubled-autopaired-characters)

I'm assuming the section in the sublime keymap is somewhere near:

`{ "keys": ["\""], "command": "insert_snippet", "args": {"contents": "\"$0\""}, "context":`

Will update this answer if I manage to figure this out soon.