# Keybind setting to skip past auto-pair end characters in Sublime Text 2

Tags: sublimetext2, key-bindings, settings

I want to be able to have the cursor move past the autopair ending character so I can continue typing my code.

I'm a noob to Sublime Text.  I was looking through here at SO and found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14260649/sublime-text-2-doubled-autopaired-characters) which uses this type of code (snippet):

```
//Tab skips to end of autopaired characters
{ "keys": ["tab"], "command": "move", "args": {"by": "characters", "forward": true},
```

And I then added to my `Default(Windows)sublime-keymap -- User` file like this:

```
//Tab skips to end of autopaired characters
    { "keys": ["tab"], "command": "move", "args": {"by": "characters", "forward": true},
      "context":[

       ]
    }
```

When I press the 'tab' key to make the cursor move past the closing autopair, the cursor moves to a tab stop (*adding 4 spaces by default*), it doesn't move "forward" like pressing an arrow key would do.

How can get the cursor just move forward using the tab key or some other key?  What am I missing/doing wrong here?  I don't want to have to use the arrow keys as doing so is not a natural keystroke from the home keys (esp. depending upon the user keyboard).  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [question you linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14260649/sublime-text-2-doubled-autopaired-characters) actually had it right—you just removed the `context` key array, which effectively told Sublime Text that you *never* wanted `Tab` to move the cursor forward by one character. Use the asker's complete key binding:

```
{ "keys": ["tab"], "command": "move", "args": {"by": "characters", "forward": true}, "context":
    [ 
        { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": true },
        { "key": "preceding_text", "operator": "not_regex_match", "operand": "[[:space:]]*", "match_all": true },
        { "key": "following_text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "^[\"'\\)\\}\\]\\_]", "match_all": true },
        { "key": "auto_complete_visible", "operator": "equal", "operand": false },
        { "key": "has_next_field", "operator": "equal", "operand": false } 
    ] 
},
```

You can read more about key bindings and contexts at the [Unofficial Docs Key Bindings page](https://sublime-text-unofficial-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/key_bindings.html).

Comment: Protractor Ninja, thanks that worked!  I don't know why the "@" sign prefix doesn't work when I try to use it to reply to posts I always have to hard code the username.

Comment: @Chris22 Good to hear! Stack Overflow strips `@user` tags when `user` happens to be the author of whatever you're commenting on. A lot of people don't like this—read [this meta question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97283/dont-remove-the-part-of-my-comment) for more details.